# Is Hataraku Maou-sama still ongoing?

Tags: the-devil-is-a-part-timer

I just wanted to know where *Hataraku Maou-sama* is over/cancelled, or whether it is still ongoing. I read it up to chapter 88, but I can't find any newer updates about the manga or anything.

Comment: Might be delayed due to Covid-19. The final light novel has also been postponed twice now due to it.

Comment: It's still on-going. The manga is serialized on [*Monthly Comic Dengeki Daioh*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dengeki_Daioh) which is published every 27th of the month. Chapter 88 was published on June 27, the next chapter should be published on July 27, unless there's an unknown circumstance.